# Subtract current time value with last 1 hour time value

Tags: postgresql, query

Table Name: Data

| Time | Data | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-05 07:45:10 | 12.0 | 9.0 |
| 2022-09-05 07:44:15 | 10.0 | 8.0 |
| 2022-09-05 07:43:12 | 13.00 | 12.0 |
| 2022-09-05 07:42:11 | 31.0 | 29.0 |
| 2022-09-05 07:41:15 | 13.0 | 12.0 |
| 2022-09-05 07:40:16 | 123.0 | 123.0 |
| 2022-09-05 07:39:11 | 2.0 | -1.0 |
| 2022-09-05 06:45:10 | 3.0 |  |
| 2022-09-05 06:44:15 | 2.0 |  |
| 2022-09-05 06:43:12 | 1.0 |  |
| 2022-09-05 06:42:11 | 2.0 |  |
| 2022-09-05 06:41:15 | 1.0 |  |
| 2022-09-05 06:39:11 | 3.0 |  |

I want a PostgreSQL query where the `Result` column with the formula (current time value - (value at one hour before)) If you subtract Data of (7:45-6:45) you will get the Result value of 7:45.

- Times are rounded **down** to the nearest minute.
- The number of measurements may vary by the hour.
- A fiddle is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/GDbj5hH0).

Comment: Does it have to be to the second? Why is 123.0 unchanged in the 2nd last result set?

Comment: Can the number of readings in an an hour vary?

Comment: Yes, the number of reading vary in an hour. No it has to be in minutes and not seconds and the 123.0 is the value of 7:40 and if you see there 6:40 does n't exists so it will take '0.0' so 123.0-0.0=123.0

Comment: Do the times in seconds round down to the nearest minute - or is it rounded to the nearest one? I.e. if the time is 07:45:55 - does that mean it's 07:45 or 07:46?

Comment: 07:45:55 means 7:45

Comment: Can you please go to dbfiddle.uk and construct a fiddle and I'll take a look tomorrow?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/GDbj5hH0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky. If there was a constant number of measurements per hour, then the [`LAG()` or `LEAD()`](https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/lead-and-lag-function-in-postgresql/) functions would have been perfect for this task, however that's not the case so we have to proceed differently.

We'll have to use a [`SELF JOIN`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-self-join/).

I'll give an example of the "exploratory" SQL that I used to obtain the answer and to show my train of thought. All of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/VCAEwsGS).

Table:

```
create table data
(
  timetable timestamp, 
  information NUMERIC,
  answer NUMERIC 
);
```

The data can be found in the fiddle.

```
--
-- "Exploratory" SQL
--

SELECT 
  DATE_TRUNC('minute', d1.timetable), d1.information, d2.information,
  date_trunc('minute', d1.timetable) - date_trunc('minute', d2.timetable),
  d1.information, d2.information,
  d1.information -  d2.information
FROM 
  data d1
LEFT join
  data d2    -- <<==== Note! JOINing the table back on to itself!
ON 
  date_trunc('minute', d2.timetable) = 
  date_trunc('minute', d1.timetable - INTERVAL '1 hour')
ORDER BY d1.timetable DESC;
```

`JOIN`ing the table back onto itself = `SELF JOIN`. We use a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-left-join/) because, as we can see from the results below, there is  a considerable number of `NULL`s in the resultset and we need to return (at least some of) these to obtain the desired result.

Result:

```
         date_trunc information information  ?column? information information   ?column?
2022-09-05 07:45:00       12.0          3.0  01:00:00       12.0          3.0   9.0
2022-09-05 07:44:00       10.0          2.0  01:00:00       10.0          2.0   8.0
2022-09-05 07:43:00       13.00         1.0  01:00:00       13.00         1.0   12.00
2022-09-05 07:42:00       31.0          2.0  01:00:00       31.0          2.0   29.0
2022-09-05 07:41:00       13.0          1.0  01:00:00       13.0          1.0   12.0
2022-09-05 07:40:00      123.0         null      null      123.0         null   null
2022-09-05 07:39:00        2.0          3.0  01:00:00        2.0          3.0   -1.0
2022-09-05 06:45:00        3.0         null      null        3.0         null   null
2022-09-05 06:44:00        2.0         null      null        2.0         null   null
2022-09-05 06:43:00        1.0         null      null        1.0         null   null
2022-09-05 06:42:00        2.0         null      null        2.0         null   null
2022-09-05 06:41:00        1.0         null      null        1.0         null   null
2022-09-05 06:39:00        3.0         null      null        3.0         null   null
```

So, we have all of the required fields, now we tidy them up and produce the desired result. I've decided to [`CAST`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-cast-operator-in-postgresql) all of the differences to `INT` using PostgreSQL's double-colon (`::`) operator. I'm also using the [`COALESCE()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-coalesce/) function to turn `NULL`s into zeros.

```
SELECT 
  DATE_TRUNC('minute', d1.timetable) AS "Timetable",
  d1.information::INTEGER,
  COALESCE(d1.information - d2.information, 0)::INTEGER  AS answer
FROM 
  data d1
LEFT JOIN data d2 
  ON DATE_TRUNC('MINUTE', d2.timetable) = 
     DATE_TRUNC('MINUTE', d1.timetable - INTERVAL '1 HOUR')
ORDER BY d1.timetable DESC;
```

Result:

```
Timetable           information answer
2022-09-05 07:45:00          12      9
2022-09-05 07:44:00          10      8
2022-09-05 07:43:00          13     12
2022-09-05 07:42:00          31     29
2022-09-05 07:41:00          13     12
2022-09-05 07:40:00         123      0
2022-09-05 07:39:00           2     -1
2022-09-05 06:45:00           3      0
2022-09-05 06:44:00           2      0
2022-09-05 06:43:00           1      0
2022-09-05 06:42:00           2      0
2022-09-05 06:41:00           1      0
2022-09-05 06:39:00           3      0
```

A few points to note:

- In your table, you **could** make the `information` and `answer` fields `INTEGER`s rather than `NUMERIC`s - makes results more legible and utilises fewer resources - but maybe you have other records which do have a fractional part?
- For the result

  - `2022-09-05 07:40:00  123 0`

  you wanted

  - `2022-09-05 07:40:00 123 123`

  This makes no sense to me - I've left it as the others with the `COALESCE()`, i.e. shows up as zero. All of the other zeros in the `answer` column would also have to show the data from the `information` column. Also, it's **highly** confusing - people would confuse raw data with results.
- In future, when asking questions like this, please **always** include a fiddle. It's a courtesy to those who are trying to help you (it eliminates duplication of effort on our/their behalf) and it provides a single point of truth for the question
- Finally, when responding to comments, please put the extra information requested **back into the question itself**. You can notify the person who requested it by putting `@` + their handle (i.e. if responding to me, you would put `@Vérace`) into a comment below theirs

Comment: Thank You @Vérace  next time I will take care of all the inputs you gave me.